# JVM off-heap memory address subject to change?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

We have a platform which heavily relies on off-heap memory in JVM. We  noticed that, from time to time, we get SIGSEGV during the GC cycle:

```
V  [libjvm.so+0x5c56cf]  G1ParScanThreadState::copy_to_survivor_space(InCSetState, oopDesc*, markOopDesc*)+0x4bf
```

I completely understand that those are quite hard to track down, but we have started narrowing down the root case.

**The question:**

If I do:

```
base = unsafe.allocateMemory(capacity);
```

and, obviously, retain the `base` for later deallocation, can (in any way) GC get involved and choose to move my native memory?

I know that GC should have no impact on this kind of memory, but I am looking for kind of authoritative answer to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That will return some virtual address pointer and AFAIK `unsafe.allocateMemory` will just call `malloc` internally. Being an *off-heap* memory, obviously GC will not touch it and that would be tremendously bad and unexpected if you later would do `Unsafe.freeMemory` with that pointer, to only find out that it moved.

Comment: Excellent, this is what I was hoping to get. Appreciate it! :)

Comment: @JovanPerovic To be even more sure: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/sun/misc/Unsafe.java#l464